# quick books api php integration

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am new to quickbooks integration, i read some documents saying there is two ways to connect quickbooks, one is quickbooks online and the other way is quickbooks windows.

i am trying to connect quickbooks windows,
for this i got download "quickbooks-php-master"
inside there is "example_web_connector.php" where i change $dsn as $dsn = 'mysql://root@localhost/quickbooks';  i dnt hav db password

and i load example.sql(it was given by quickbooks-php-master) for this quickbooks database.

and they saying to install web connector,  i download this and install, its  asking .qwc file

i given qwc file as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>QuickBooks Integrator</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>localhost/quick/books/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>localhost/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>test user</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

And then i given above qwc file its saying QWC1039 error,
 error 80040154

can you give me the procedure steps, am I missing anything

In "example_web_connector_qwc.php" there is

```
$appurl = 'https://your-domain-name/path/to/soap/server.php';   
$appsupport = 'https://your-domain-name/get-help-here.php';
```

What i can give for these two lines

Is there any mistakes in my grammar, please forgive me...

regards

Narendra

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're following the quick-start guide located here:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Some specific feedback:

> i dnt hav db password

If you don't have your MySQL database password, then you need to contact your web hosting provider and ask them for it. No one on StackOverflow is going to be able to provide this for you. Contact your web host.

> and i load example.sql(it was given by quickbooks-php-master) for this quickbooks database.

You don't need example.sql if you follow the quick-start guide.

> localhost/quick/books/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php

That URL from your .QWC file is not a valid URL. URLs have either `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of them. That doesn't. You need to specify a valid URL.

> localhost/

This is also not a valid URL. See notes above. Specify a valid URL.

> In "example_web_connector_qwc.php" there is ...

If you use the .QWC file you created already, but fix the URLs, then you don't need `example_web_connector_qwc.php` at all.

> And then i given above qwc file its saying QWC1039 error, error 80040154

If you continue to get errors, you need to post your Web Connector log file, or look in the log file and find *the actual error message*. The Web Connector will throw the same error code for many different reasons, so without an actual error message, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi thank u for reply ,  I followed the http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start link only,          1. i dnt hav db password means there is no password for connect my db for the user root, so given in $dsn = 'mysql://root@localhost/quickbooks'; in "example_web_connector.php".    2. I install Quickbooks simple start 2009, Install Quickbooks web connector

Comment: That $dsn is fine if there is no password. Fix all of the other things I mentioned and you should be all set.

Comment: Hi keith,Today i tried Quick books online for testing purpose, i run "/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php"with credentials then it says "QuickBooksPHPDevKit-IPPIntuitAnywhereDemoApp" "CONNECTED" and green color with Realm: details,thats fine,then i run "/example_customer_add.php", by changing different names inside, to add some customers,and then i check quickbooks accounts "https://qbo.intuit.com/app/customers"  where i can see all added customers,its working fine,and i run some other file "example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_query.php" its  gives list. it means i did correct for quick books online

Comment: Now i would like to follow the step by step for quickbooks windows as for the http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start link. Here In step 1. says install Quick books, For this i installed Quickbooks simple start 2009 version, is this correct or any other licensed version required, if so can you give me free version name/link. And 2,3,4,5,6 steps i did correct only, can you clarify the 7th an 8th step with possible file change(.QWC file <AppSupport>…</AppSupport> i am using local machine what i can give for this tag), 9th step i can do, regards Narendra.

Comment: If you're having trouble with your .QWC file, then post the .QWC file you're using. The one you posted above and below does not have valid URLs in it. Read my comments about URLs. URLs start with http:// or https://

Comment: Hi keith, thanks for your Patience at my issue,  <?xml version="1.0"?><QBWCXML><AppName>QbInt</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://localhost/quick/API/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>http://localhost/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>tes</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>

Comment: Actually i am giving for <AppURL> with http:// only. followed by above link, but when posting here stack overflow asks me give valid domain name instead of localhost, so removed in http://.  one more thing when i load to quickbooks web connector with this qwc file, first asks for confirmation ssl, then i click yes/ok , it says install quickbooks(QBWC1039 error), if not yet install. I installed quick books simple start 2009 version,is this version ok or any other licensed version required,can you give me free version or link for install quickbooks for test in my localmachine. regards Narendra

Comment: There is no free link. I don't know if that version will work or not -- it's very old and unsupported, so it may not. You may have to just buy a newer version.

Comment: Keith thanks a lot for not letting me so much time on this thing, can you give me version or path for standard licensed version,for quick books windows.  Apart from this my following procedure is correct or am i miss any mandatory things.    regards Narendra.

Comment: You can buy QuickBooks on Amazon or directly from Intuit's website. QuickBooks Pro 2014 for Windows should be fine for developing against.